# limiting number of records in mysql query

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

I have written a query:

```
SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W FROM Meter_Data 
WHERE TimeStamp Between 1356908255 AND 1356944255 
OR (TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356911855 AND 1356947855) 
OR (TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356915455 AND 1356951455) 
OR (TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356919055 AND 1356955055) 
OR (TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356922655 AND 1356958655) 
AND MeterID = @meterID 
AND DeviceID = @deviceID 
ORDER BY TimeStamp
```

but problem is that it returns multiple records for every between clause but i just want one. LIMIT will limit total records = 1 for whole query. so cannot use that. please help!

Comment: How do you decide which timestamp / fwdhr / w to take in each range?

Comment: Note that `MeterID` and `DeviceID` are checked for the last `TimeStamp` range only. If you want them to be checked for all `TimeStamp` ranges, but parentheses around `TimeStamp` ranges (after `WHERE` and before first `AND`).

Comment: You can Group By FwdHr, and Max(TimeStamp)

Is that what you want ? do you need other fields ?

Comment: i just need one in each range - anyone from that range.. it doesn;t matter but i need just one for each range not all.

Comment: @Mzf are you saying MAX(TimeStamp) BETWEEN 1900202020 AND 1902292929 ?? and what purpose does group by serves?

Comment: @InderpalSingh I understand that you want 1 record for all ranges, from your other comment I understand that you want 1 from each range

Comment: I think create temp table and then join both table will be cleaner

Comment: creating temp table?? like ??

Comment: @Mzfi used max(timestamp) but its throwing exception invalid use of group function.. i have not included groupby yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a series of UNIONed queries:-

```
(SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W 
FROM Meter_Data 
WHERE TimeStamp Between 1356908255 AND 1356944255 
AND MeterID = @meterID
AND DeviceID = @deviceID 
ORDER BY TimeStamp
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W 
FROM Meter_Data 
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356911855 AND 1356947855
AND MeterID = @meterID 
AND DeviceID =     @deviceID 
ORDER BY TimeStamp
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W 
FROM Meter_Data 
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356915455 AND 1356951455
AND MeterID = @meterID 
AND DeviceID =     @deviceID 
ORDER BY TimeStamp
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W 
FROM Meter_Data 
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356919055 AND 1356955055
AND MeterID = @meterID 
AND DeviceID =     @deviceID 
ORDER BY TimeStamp
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W 
FROM Meter_Data 
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356922655 AND 1356958655
AND MeterID = @meterID 
AND DeviceID =     @deviceID 
ORDER BY TimeStamp
LIMIT 1)
```

You might need to change the parameter names and pass them multiple times depending on you DB class

Another possibility (but not tested) would be to have a subselect getting the max timestamp within each range for the meter id / device id, adding a CASE statement to get which range a row is and grouping by that, then joining the results back against the main table.

Note that if there are duplicate timestamps for a meter id / device id combination then this will not work correctly.

Not sure if this will be faster or slower!

```
SELECT Meter_Data.TimeStamp, Meter_Data.FwdHr, Meter_Data.W 
FROM Meter_Data 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) AS MaxTimestamp, MeterID, DeviceID,
CASE 
    WHEN TimeStamp Between 1356908255 AND 1356944255 THEN 1
    WHEN TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356911855 AND 1356947855 THEN 2
    WHEN TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356915455 AND 1356951455 THEN 3
    WHEN TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356919055 AND 1356955055 THEN 4
    WHEN TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356922655 AND 1356958655 THEN 5
END AS GroupNo
FROM Meter_Data 
WHERE (TimeStamp Between 1356908255 AND 1356944255 
OR TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356911855 AND 1356947855
OR TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356915455 AND 1356951455
OR TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356919055 AND 1356955055
OR TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356922655 AND 1356958655) 
AND MeterID = @meterID 
AND DeviceID = @deviceID 
GROUP BY MeterID, DeviceID, GroupNo) Sub1
ON Meter_Data.MeterID = Sub1.MeterID
AND Meter_Data.DeviceID = Sub1.DeviceID
AND Meter_Data.TimeStamp = Sub1.MaxTimestamp
ORDER BY Meter_Data.TimeStamp
```

Comment: It should be fairly efficient. I can't think of a more efficient way to do it

Comment: Edited with a further solution

Comment: i have used upper solution by making union of all but its returning only one row at all when i change to limit 2 it returns only 2 rows .. but it should return 2 rows for each range.

Comment: Mmm, interesting. Think it might be applying the final LIMIT to all the clauses. Try putting brackets around each select (including its LIMIT) in the UNION

Comment: That should work. I have edited my code above to put the brackets like this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31189/discussion-between-inderpal-singh-and-kickstart)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do this using variables.  Here is one approach:

```
SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W
FROM (select md.*, 
             (case when TimeStamp Between 1356908255 AND 1356944255 then @rn1 := @rn1 + 1
                   when TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356911855 AND 1356947855 then @rn2 := @rn2 + 1
                   when TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356915455 AND 1356951455 then @rn3 := @rn3 + 1
                   when TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356919055 AND 1356955055 then @rn4 := @rn4 + 1
                   when TimeStamp BETWEEN 1356922655 AND 1356958655 then @rn5 := @rn5 + 1
              end) as rn
      from Meter_Data cross join
           (select @rn1 := 0, @rn2 := 0, @rn3 := 0, @rn4 := 0, @rn5 := 0) const
      WHERE MeterID = @meterID AND DeviceID = @deviceID 
     ) md
where rn = 1
ORDER BY TimeStamp;
```

This defines a separate variable for each group.  It then increments the variable when seen, returning the result in the `rn` "column".  This just selects the first value encountered.

Comment: Unfortunately this suffers in the same way (as myself and the OP discussed) in that the timestamp ranges can overlap, but is a neat way of doing things.